# Loop input an input X amount of times

Tags: java, algorithm

i am working on a Mock Test and i am struggling to create a loop that will cycle the input 12 times while adding each input to a sum.

> - Determines the average weight of a person over a particular year.
> - For each month, your algorithm should input the person's weight for that month (a positive real number). Your algorithm should loop,
>     repeating the input, until the input is positive.
> - Finally, your algorithm output the average weight.

After looking through lecture notes on Iteration Control Structures i have come up with this:

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{
double month, sum;
sum = 0;
for (month = 1; month <= 12; month++)
    {
    month = ConsoleInput.readDouble("Enter weight for each month");
    sum += month;
    }
System.out.println("Sum total is: " +sum);
}
```

Unfortunately all this does for me is repeat the input an infinite amount of times until i enter a number greater than 12.

I just want to make ConsoleInput cycle 12 times. Does anyone know the best way about this using while, do-while and for loops? I'm not allowed to use arrays, objects etc at this point in the course.

Any advice is appreciated cheers.

Comment: It is maybe not so clever to use `month` as your loop counter and as the storage for the user input, but I guess you had a good reason for this.

Comment: Also try debugging your program and you can see exactly what's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Possibly do the Following in order to make your Program Work.Just add one more variable monthweight and assign the user input

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{
double month, sum,monthweight;
sum = 0;
for (month = 1; month <= 12; month++)
    {

    monthweight = ConsoleInput.readDouble("Enter weight for each month");
    if(monthweight > 0.0M)
      {
        sum += monthweight;
      }
    else
     {
       break;
     }
    }
    System.out.println("Sum total is: " +sum);
}
```

Comment: I left one thing For printing Average use it as System.out.println("Average weight is: " +sum/12);

Comment: That's alright all i needed is to figure out how to cycle my input 12 times. From here i will loop validation of input and create submodules to calculate and truncate average weight. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You're using `month` in 2 ways, both to count to 12 and to receive the person's weight in. I think if you would assign `ConsoleInput.readDouble(..)` to another variable, and add that to the `sum`, your program will work better.

Comment: The count to 12 was totally wrong and wasn't my intention, i thought it would cycle my input 12 times. I didn't want to count anything, i just wanted to cycle month = ConsoleInput.readDouble X amount of times. But i have no idea how to do that.